# Visual Studio C++ Windows Store Linkage error

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to build Windows Store (8.1) application I get bunch of errors like:

```
Error   17  error C2598: linkage specification must be at global scope  d:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\winrt\activation.h  54  1   App7
    26  IntelliSense: not a class or struct name    d:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\inspectable.h 100 17  App7
```

It all started when I tried to compile code which used IInspectable (xaml and directx interoop) - now I can't build any C++ Windows Store project (even clean project templates). I tried to repair and reinstall Visual Studio - it didn't help.

Comment: You get this error when the *extern* keyword appears inside of a function.  This strongly suggests that you are missing a } ending brace somewhere.  Or accidentally edited an SDK header file.

Comment: This happened to me as well with fresh VS2017 install compiling a C++ file which compiles fine under VS2015, as well as VS2017 using VS2015 platform toolset. SDK version makes no difference.
Complaints in setjmp.h (not actively included), mmintrin.h and xmmintrin.h. Line indicated has _CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER which is extern "C" + a __pragma: Will try to find out more.

Comment: In my case it is dependent on the use of intrinsics through #include <intrin.h>, such as __cpuid(), _xgetbv(), _mm_cvtsd_f64(). intrin.h also includes setjmp.h

Comment: Problem for me is solved, i.e. 'gone away'. Version VS: 15.1 (26403.3), Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA589.